# AVPlayer Stream status

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this methods for playing video with AVPlayer:

```
        audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] retain];
        avPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer] retain];
        [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];

        [audioPlayer play];
```

I search for a way to get notification every-time in the stream process (something like 1%,10%,25%,50%,60%......), can i get something like this from `AVPlayer` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation, you need to implement this method:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:

An example:

```
[mPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 1)
         queue:NULL
         usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
             NSLog(@"%lld %d ",mPlayer.currentTime.value,mPlayer.currentTime.timescale);
         }
];
```

To get the total time of the video you can do:

```
mPlayer.currentItem.duration
```

As well you can get the currentTime from the item:

```
mPlayer.currentItem.currentTime
```

**Edit**:

take a look at [CurrentItem reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

you probably want some method like:

loadedTimeRanges

Comment: OK, this is the playing process time, but what i looking for is the download process that is fast from the playing.

Comment: Ok, I edit the answer, you can get informations about the item. You can get arrays from what is already loaded and so on.